# Warning: Error in : GeomInteractivePoint was built with an incompatible version of ggproto

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(selectedData(), aes(x = sharpe, y = returns, tooltip = fund, data_id = fund, color=sd)) +  geom_point_interactive(size=1)
```

What was the issue ?

Comment: Are you using the github version of ggplot? Does the error message continue with: "Please reinstall the package that provides this extension." There have been some updates to ggproto in ggplot2. Try re-installing ggiraph.

Comment: Check "Extensions" in ggplot [NEWS](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md)

Comment: where do I download GitHub of ggplot ? I thought I can download from r-studio cran ? My R- version is 3.3.2

Comment: thx @sandy-muspratt. It seems that pakage needs to be reinstalled: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md#extensions