# Error: ScalesList was built with an incompatible version of ggproto

Tags: r, ggplot2, slidify, ggproto

I'm doing a presentation in slidfy, using the deckjs framework.
Everything was ok, but suddenly this chunk of code:

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +  geom_point(color = 'red') + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, size = 0.5, se = F)
```

stopped working and shows this error instead:

```
## Error: ScalesList was built with an incompatible version of ggproto.
## Please reinstall the package that provides this extension.
```

The code works perfectly when executed from source or console... But it doesn't work anymore from the R markdown. The function that fails is the stat_smooth(). The rest visualizes ok if executed without the smooth.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582884/warning-error-in-geominteractivepoint-was-built-with-an-incompatible-version) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642850/ggmap-error-geomrasterann-was-built-with-an-incompatible-version-of-ggproto) a similar error is reported, and the solution offered is to reinstall ggplot and the packages from github, but I'm not sure which packages should I install, and, besides, the code only fails from Rmarkdown, and not when executed from console or source.

Thanks

Comment: Cleanly start R (in vanilla mode if necessary). Run your existing code (that generates the errors). run `sessionInfo()`. See list of pkgs. Reinstall/upgrade those packages. Try again. NOTE that you should install ggplot2 first before any pkgs that include ggplot2 geoms/scales/etc.

Comment: That's what I did... The problem is that the code works! But from console or source. Not from the R markdown. That's the problem.

Comment: how are you knitting the rmd? the knit cmd in RStudio or via function call?

Comment: I'm knitting it in RStudio. What puzzles me is that it has been working correctly till today. I've installed some packages lately, but none (or at least, not as far as I know) related to ggplot.

Comment: How does order of package loading differ between knit and "script" document?

Comment: Roman, how can I figure that out? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you could `knitr::purl()` your document, and run the R source code it produces to see where it chokes.

Comment: Print out the results of `.libPaths()` in each environment. I'm guessing they will be different and that the error message is telling you htere is an outdated version on one of the library directories.

Comment: @42- I get the same output in both cases: "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very strange; now things are back to normal.

I did what @baptiste suggested, and the R source code just worked ok.
After that, I knitted the Rmarkdown again and the error had disappeared!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem in RMarkdown after updating ggplot2. I was loading a workspace with plots created with the older version of ggplot2. The solution was to recreate that workspace with the updated version, and now RMarkdown works.

Comment: This was the situation for me. I had to re-run all of my existing plots, then re-save my environment and then the Markdown compilation worked again.

Answer (score 0):

in Feb 2017 the same error was resolved by re-installing all the packages (RStudio - Tools - Check for package updates)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with **geom_tufteboxplot** . I first updated ggplot2 & ggthemes package, then detached all ggplot related packages and reloaded them. It worked for me.